# 3.3v sensor to switch water pump

Tags: power, sensor, fluid-pump

I have a PIR sensor that when triggered, gives out a 3.3V signal. I'm trying to use that to switch on a 5V water pump, and I'm assuming I will use a transistor. The sensor only puts out 10mA, while the pump draws around 1A. How would I switch on the pump with the sensor?

Thanks!

Comment: Logic level MOSFET instead of a BJT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a logic level (Vgs-threshold <= 2V would be good) MOSFET (N Channel for a low side power switch, it's the easiest).

The following diagram is something I put together to teach my robotics club how to do basic power circuitry, in this case to drive a 12V DC PC case fan. In your case, the fan motor is just a 5V motor, but still is essentially a fan/motor. The protection diode shown is still important.

[image: N channel MOSFET as low side switch]

In this case the "switch" is your 3.3V sensor output. The PIR sensor output may not be high for very long, you should perhaps use a 555 timer and some buffers/inverters to keep the signal to the MOSFET high for longer, with the RC constant as something reasonable for your application.

Depending how your 5V rail is supplied to the pump, you may want to put some bulk capacitance such as a few hundred microfarads, or even a few thousand, to prevent it from drawing the line low during current transients as the pump turns on. This same advice holds true for using servos, and many other motors. Always buffer the power supply with local bulk capacitance!

Comment: Cool, thanks. Do you know of any particular one that will work for my circuit?

Comment: Well it depends if you want surface mount of through-hole, and which supplier you will buy from. Basically you want a MOSFET which is N Channel, at least 12V Drain-Source rated, but go for 20V just in case (and to be useful for 12V circuits too) and at least 3A rated. And remember the gate drive voltage (Vgs-th on the datasheets) should be around about 1-2V, so that 3.3V will turn it fully on.

Comment: Would the FQP30N06L work well? It says the Vgs(th) max value is 2.5V, but elsewhere it says it was tested at 10V.

Comment: almost all MOSFET datasheets will show values for a test voltage of 10V at the gate. Look at the Vgs chart showing Drain-Source current for particular voltages.

Comment: 2.5V only lets through 250 microamps, you need 1 amp, there is a huge difference! Luckily the voltage increase to 3.3V should let through much more than 250 microamps

Comment: @Thesciman it looks like 3.3V lets through between 10-15 Amps, that is fine. You can use that device.